# How to create button that plays media

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to find a way to create a button that plays media with `mediaelement.js`.
I tried `player.stop`, then `player.play`.
But `player.stop` is not available.

Comment: Dear Tron Hoang, can provide some code fragments that clarifies your issue? What exact is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> HTML5 defines a "pause" method, but not a "stop" method. The "stop"
>   method is only present to support Flash RTMP streaming, so you should
>   use the "pause" method in all other cases.

You should not use `.stop()`. You can use `setCurrentTime(0)` if you want to play the same track from start.